# Open file, write in to it and print out the result

Tags: python

I am yet again one of the people studying Learn Python the hard way series and
in excercise 17 came across with:

```
out_file = open(to_file, 'w')
out_file.write(indata)
```

So following some instructions i converted it in to a form of:

```
with open(to_file, 'w') as out_file:
  out_file.write(indata)
```

Don't know if it's the best way to do thing but it was instructed to use when reading from file. So really my question is how can i print out what i wrote in to out_file.
I have tried simply using following:

```
with open(to_file, 'rw+') as out_file:
  out_file.write(indata)
  print out_file.read()
```

and several other ways, but i can't get it to print anything. Just wondering if is it even possible to do even this way or do i have to open the file seperately again to print it out.

And including another question here regarding the topic how i use print with `with`

```
 with open(to_file, 'r') as out_file:
  print out_file.read()
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why don't you just `print indata`? And what exactly is the problem with the last code snippet?

Comment: Use `r+`. [tutorial here.](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files)

Comment: After writing the data, you're probably at the end of the file. So there's nothing to read there: you'll need to move the file pointer back to beginning of the file and read from there.

Comment: Nice point there Joel, didn't think of that. Just thought if i add strings to file with existing strings this information would be useful. I may have have been over thinking it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem with the following snippet:

```
with open(to_file, 'r+') as out_file:
  out_file.write(indata)
  print out_file.read()
```

is that the file's index will be at the end, and thus there will be nothing to read. To solve that, just use `seek()`:

```
 with open(to_file, 'r+') as out_file:
  out_file.write(indata)
  out_file.seek(0)
  for line in out_file.readline():
   print line
```

Though, writing and reading in the same block of code makes little sense in real life, as you should still have the data you've written, and because I/O to disk are much more expensive than the RAM you were using to keep the data, so you may just do:

```
 with open(to_file, 'w') as out_file:
  out_file.write(indata)

 with open(to_file, 'r') as in_file:
  for line in in_file.readline():
   print(line)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just print what you are writing to the file (I'm assuming it's a string):

```
with open(to_file, 'rw+') as out_file:
    out_file.write(indata)
    print indata
```

About your second question, you could read and print lines seperately:

```
with open(to_file, 'r') as out_file:
    for l in out_file.readlines()
        print l
```

Answer (score 0):

After you write file, you have to rewind it to the start in order to read what you've just written:

```
In [152]: with open('test.file', 'w+') as out_file:
    out_file.write(data)
    out_file.seek(0)
    print out_file.read()
   .....:     
test string
```